# Returning jSON with Partial View HTML Snippet to add to the DOM

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm relatively new to using ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI, I am rewriting my website and subsequently moving away from using PHP.

I have a page where users can add something new, a Quiz Password.  Using PHP and jQuery I had a page that I would use jQUERY $.ajax to post the details of the quiz password.  I used to return JSON with the following fields:

- Success - Whether the item was added to the database
- ErrorMessage - Populated with an error message if there is one
- Html - The HTML of the object which would be added to the DOM

I decided that as I would be Adding, Updating and Deleting the quiz password, that I would use a WebAPI controller.

I have got as far as returning the Success BOOL and ErrorMessage value if there is one, but I'm not sure how I can populate the `Html` value with escaped HTML that makes use of the partial view that I use for an item on the page.

Here's my WebAPI controller so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using uQuiz.Domain.Abstract;
using uQuiz.Domain.Models;
using uQuiz.WebUI.Models.Api;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using uQuiz.Domain.Helpers;

namespace uQuiz.WebUI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class PasswordController : ApiController
    {
        private IQuizEntities Context;

        public PasswordController(IQuizEntities context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Password/5
        public object Get(int id)
        {
            // Check that quiz password exists
            if (this.Context.EntitySet<QuizPassword>().Any(x => x.Id == id))
            {
                QuizPassword quizPassword = this.Context.EntitySet<QuizPassword>().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault<QuizPassword>();

                ApiQuizPassword model = new ApiQuizPassword()
                {
                    Id = quizPassword.Id,
                    Password = quizPassword.Password
                };

                return model;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // POST: api/Password
        public ApiResult Post([FromBody]ApiQuizPassword apiQuizPassword)
        {
            Quiz quiz = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>().Find(apiQuizPassword.QuizId);
            int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            ApiResult result = new ApiResult();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Return the first validation result
                result.Success = false;
                result.ErrorMessage = ModelState.First().Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
                return result;
            }

            if (!quiz.IsQuizOwner(userId))
            {
                result.Success = false;
                result.ErrorMessage = "Logged in user is not quiz owner";
                return result;
            }

            if (quiz.DoesPasswordAlreadyExistForQuiz(apiQuizPassword.Password))
            {
                result.Success = false;
                result.ErrorMessage = "Password already exists for this quiz";
                return result;
            }

            using (var transaction = this.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    QuizPassword quizPassword = this.Context.EntitySet<QuizPassword>().Create();

                    // Assign posted values
                    quizPassword.Password = apiQuizPassword.Password;
                    quizPassword.QuizId = apiQuizPassword.QuizId;

                    // Assign default values
                    quizPassword.RemainingUses = 0;
                    quizPassword.UnlimitedUses = true;
                    quizPassword.UseCount = 0;
                    quizPassword.Deleted = false;
                    quizPassword.CreatedTime = TimeHelper.UnixTimestamp;

                    this.Context.EntitySet<QuizPassword>().Add(quizPassword);
                    this.Context.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();

                    result.Success = true;
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    result.Success = false;
                    result.ErrorMessage = "Failed to save the quiz password";
                    return result;
                }
                finally
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        // PUT: api/Password/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Password/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            using (var transaction = this.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    QuizPassword quizPassword = this.Context.EntitySet<QuizPassword>().Find(id);
                    this.Context.Entry(quizPassword).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    this.Context.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my API result class that I'm returning from the `Post` method within my controller:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public HtmlString Html { get; set; }
}
```

My partial view is called `_QuizPasswordPartial`.

Am I totally missing the mark, should I only be returning HTML from my `Get` method?

Either way, I'd like to return my rendered partial from my controller within a JSON result.

Answer (score 0):

Web API returns data (JSON/XML) not a rendered view (HTML). Call the API with Javascript, retrieve the raw data and update the view inside the browser.

Comment: There are times when you need to return encoded html within the result to add to the dom.  I've found a way to do it, i might post it as an answer...